# Rails query user first name on join model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

this situation that find the user on a join model is seems tricky than usual

```
 class ConversationParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :conversation
      attr_accessible :user_id
    end



   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :conversation_participants

  end
```

I'm trying to find the conversation_participant with the fisrt_name with this query

```
 user = User.where('conversation_participant like ? or first_name like ?', query, query)
```

but the query did not return the user_participant and the user first_name either.

someone can spare a hint please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the `%` for the sql `LIKE` operator

```
query = params[:query] # or something ...
User.where('conversation_participant LIKE :query OR first_name LIKE :query', query: "%#{query}%")
```

Comment: but shows:


User.where('conversation_participant LIKE :query OR first_name LIKE :query', query: "%#{query}%")
  User Load (14.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (conversation_participant LIKE '%%' OR first_name LIKE '%%')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: conversation_participant: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (conversation_participant LIKE '%%' OR first_name LIKE '%%')


so i have to include %?

Comment: Well, do you have such a column `conversation_participant` in the table?

Comment: yes conversation_participants. and i put the s. just a minute i'll check

Comment: The log is showing : SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (conversation_participant LIKE '%%' OR first_name LIKE '%%')

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<User::FriendlyIdActiveRecordRelation:0x007fe507db8e38>):
  app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:69:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:49:in `create'

Comment: wtf the id is have something to do with find with first_name!